# Julia: How to create a new column in DataFrames.jl by adding two columns using `transform` or `@transform`?

Tags: dataframe, julia

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=1:3)
```

How do I create a new column `c` such that `c = a+b` element wise?

Can't figure it out by reading the `transform` doc.

I know that

`df[!, :c] = df.a .+ df.b`

works but I want to use `transform` in a chain like this

```
@chain df begin
  @transform(c = :a .+ :b)
  @where(...)
  groupby(...)
end
```

The above syntax doesn't work with DataFramesMeta.jl

Comment: great question. In my work I try to organize transformations in compact pipelines like this, I came here to learn this very thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an answer using DataFrames.jl.

To create a new data frame:

```
julia> transform(df, [:a,:b] => (+) => :c)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      2
   2 │     2      2      4
   3 │     3      3      6
```

and for an in-place operation:

```
julia> transform!(df, [:a,:b] => (+) => :c)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      2
   2 │     2      2      4
   3 │     3      3      6
```

or

```
julia> insertcols!(df, :c => df.a + df.b)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c     
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      1      2
   2 │     2      2      4
   3 │     3      3      6
```

The difference between `transform!` and `insertcols!` is that `insertcols!` will error if `:c` column is present in the data frame, while `transform!` will overwrite it.

Comment: Do you know how I might do this if the operation I need to do is complicated? For example, suppose I want to create a new column where ````c[1] = a[1], c[2] = a[1] + a[2], c[3] = a[1] + a[2] + a[3]````, etc. I can calculate the elements easily enough with a for loop, but I'm not sure how to do it with transform and insertcols.

Comment: use the `transform(df, :a => cumsum => :c)`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

```
@chain df begin
  @transform!(@byrow :c = :a + :b)
  ...
end;
```